# Get XML element value using XML to Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

A snippet of the XML im querying is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<metadata created="2014-11-03T18:13:02.769Z" xmlns="http://example.com/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://example.com/ns/ext#-2.0">
    <customer-list count="112" offset="0">
        <customer id="5f6ab597-f57a-40da-be9e-adad48708203" type="Person" ext:score="100">
            <name>Bobby Smith</name>
            <gender>male</gender>
            <country>US</country>
            <birth-span>
                <start>1965-02-18</start>
                <end>false</end>
            </birth-span>
```

The code im writing to get the elements is

```
    GetCustomer = from c in XDoc.Descendants(ns + "customer")
                      select
                      new Customer
                      {
                          Name = c.Element(ns + "name").ToString(),
                          Gender = Convert.ToString(c.Element(ns + "gender")),
                          BeginDate = c.Elements("birth-span").Any() ? c.Element("start").Value.ToString() : "No data found"
```

The problem i have is with `birth-span`, i never seem to get the value if birth-span exists (there are some records which do not contain the birth-span element). For the records that do contain the birth-span element i have added the namespace variable which doesnt work (throws the error that object is not set to an instance)

```
 BeginDate = c.Elements(ns + "birth-span").Any() ? c.Element(ns + "start").Value.ToString() : "No data found"
```

Ive added different variations but either i get the value No Data found OR an error (Seems to be object not set to an instance). Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're treating `start` as a direct descendant of `c` (or `customer`) by doing this:

```
BeginDate = c.Elements("birth-span").Any() ?
    c.Element("start").Value.ToString() :
    "No data found"
```

When you actually want to do treat `start` as a direct descendant of the `birth-span` element like so:

```
BeginDate = c.Elements("birth-span").Any() ?
    c.Element("birth-span").Element("start").Value.ToString() :
    "No data found"
```

There's room for improvement though. Is there either zero or one `birth-span` element, or zero or many? As it seems like it's zero or one, you could do this and make it a little clearer:

```
var customers = from c in doc.Descendants("customer")
                let birthSpan = c.Element("birth-span")
                select new
                {
                    Name = c.Element("name").Value,
                    Gender = c.Element("gender").Value,
                    BeginDate = birthSpan == null ?
                        "No data found" :
                        birthSpan.Element("start").Value
                };
```

Also, there's no need to call `Convert.ToString` or `.ToString()` on any of these. If you want a `string`, `.Value()` will do. If you actually want it typed to something else, directly cast it and let the conversion operators do the work:

```
var customers = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("customer")
                let birthSpan = c.Element("birth-span")
                select new
                {
                    Name = (string)c.Element("name"),
                    Gender = (string)c.Element("gender"),
                    BeginDate = birthSpan == null ?
                        (DateTime?)null :
                        (DateTime?)birthSpan.Element("start")
                };
```

There's a great article about that [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx).

Comment: `Namespace` to be included `...(ns+"customer")`

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Before going into the advanced theories i tried getting the basic way to work first by using this code BeginDate = c.Elements("birth-span").Any() ?
    c.Element("birth-span").Element("start").Value.ToString() :
    "No data found" but still this returns *"No data found"?*

Comment: Did you re-add the `ns+` as @Thirisangu suggests? I removed them to try to simplify, but they will still be necessary in your code.